# How to sort two arrays based on the first array

Tags: c++

I have two arrays, one for points and another for holding names. I want to sort the array with the points in ascending order and to the name array to go along with their corresponding point array. I was wondering how I could do that.
Here's what I've tried so far

```
string sName[noS];
char sex[noS];           //Variable to hold the sex information of the students
char gpa[noS];           //Variable to hold the GPA
char essayGrade[noS];
int convGpa[noS];
int convEssayGrade[noS];
double overallPoint[noS];
pair<double, string> pairs[noS];
int want_len = noS;



pairs[i] = make_pair(overallPoint[i], sName[i]);
                    cout << endl <<"Over all point of " << pairs[i].second << ": " << pairs[i].first << endl;
                    sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end());
```

all necessary variables have been initialized.

Comment: Did you consider using `std::map` instead of 2 arrays?

Comment: Could you tell me how I can implement that? And I don't think I could do that because overallPoints is not unique.

Comment: If the keys are not unique, you can use `std::multimap`.

Comment: You might want to actually do a search on SO.   This question, or variations of it, have been asked several times in the last couple of weeks.   Various people have given workable answers to a number of those questions, even if not upvoted or accepted [so this thread cannot be marked as a duplicate of those].

Comment: I have spent all day searching for it. Most answers are in different languages, which I can not translate to c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you can use that (map) :

```
     #include<map>
      using namesapce std;
        map<double, string> myMap;
        myMap.insert(name of the pair you want to insert)
```

std::map sorts it self automaticaly

Comment: @Bereket You will have a sorted by key associative container ( in your case: number, name), you can read about    std::map    here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/ || In terms of multi key with the same value you can use std::multimap

Comment: As I have said before on the comments of the question, the double value may not be unique.

Comment: @BereketNybGobeze So just use std::multimap, it's the same syntax as std::map, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy approach => use std::stable_sort. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort

Not so lazy approach => Rewrite your design. Have an array of structure that contain name and point information. (Merge this info) Sort this array of structures based on a comparison function using the point member.

If you insist on using this design, I'd write my own little sort function that would also swap the name array position while swapping the point position... But that's not very nice is it?